# Magento 2.3: Attribute swatch not working in category listing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

In console i can see error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'swatchImage' of undefined

In the code i can see the main div set like this:

```
<div class="swatch-opt-3359" data-role="swatch-option-3359"></div>
```

Why is the swatch not displaying in category listing? The setting "Show swatched on product list" is enabled too yes.

Do I need to set any additional settings with the product?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me how are you defining the swatch for any product? Steps please. I am able to define it and it is working for me. If you can let me know how are you defining it, I can help you in this.

Comment: The switch function is working on the product site, but not on category site (inside listing). Could I still do something wrong?

Comment: can you share how you created swatch? I have created one and it is working for me on listing and PDP both.

Comment: i have created it with import configurable products. Do you need any specific information? I will gladly write them here. Thank you!